# Should IUIAutomation cache requests be used from within the same process?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ui-automation

The Windows [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-cachingforclients) say that when retrieving properties of an IUIAutomation element, you should build an IUIAutomation cache request, since "cross-process" calls are inefficient:

> When using Microsoft UI Automation, clients often need to retrieve
> multiple properties for multiple automation elements. A client could
> retrieve individual properties one element at a time by using the
> property retrieval methods such as **IUIAutomationElement::CurrentName**
> or **CurrentAccessKey**. However, this method is slow and inefficient
> because it requires a cross-process call for each property being
> retrieved. To improve performance, clients can use the caching (also
> called bulk fetching) capabilities of UI Automation. Caching enables a
> client to retrieve all of the desired properties for all of the
> desired elements with a single method call. The client can then
> retrieve the individual properties from the cache as needed, and can
> get a new snapshot of the cache periodically, generally in response to
> events that signify changes in the UI.

My question is: what if you're accessing elements in-process?  For example, let's say you're making a browser helper object and accessing elements of the Explorer window that loads your object?  Should cache requests still be used then, or is it unnecessary? Would that make any difference?

Comment: In-process is inherently quicker, so probably no point.

Comment: Clients can [use the caching to improve performance of cross-process calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-cachingforclients). Compared to server-side UI Automation providers, there is [less benefit when accessing client-side providers such as the default providers for Win32 controls.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/caching-in-ui-automation-clients)